# Wieso schreibt man im Deutschen "Schüler/in" statt nur "Schüler"?

Tags: word-usage, gender-neutrality

Warum muss man immer auch das weibliche Wort nennen, wenn man von einer bestimmten Gruppe von Menschen, Beruf usw. spricht? Wäre es denn nicht leichter bloß "Schüler" zu sagen?

Und was hat es mit dieser Schreibweise "SchülerIn" auf sich? Ist sie korrekt oder nur umgangssprachlich verwendet?

Comment: Umgangssprache wird gesprochen, aber nur selten geschrieben. Dementsprechend wird auch weder Schüler/in, noch SchülerIn irgendwie gesprochen, weil es sich nicht sprechen lässt - jedenfalls nicht angemessen in unauffälliger Sprache, die Betonungen nach eigenen Gründen setzen will, nicht um einen Bürokratismus hervorzuheben. Es gibt aber natürlich Sturköpfe, die es versuchen. Diese sind aber äußerst rar.

Comment: Es wäre auch korrekt, einfach nur "Schüler" zu sagen, da das grammatikalische Geschlecht für den Oberbegriff im Deutschen nichts mit dem biologischen Geschlecht zu tun hat.

Comment: Eine weitere Variante (die mir persönlich mehr behagt) ist, an geeigneter Stelle eines Textes/einer Text/*in darauf hinzuweisen, dass stets beide (oder oder besser: alle) Geschlechter (Oder Geschlechter/*innen?) gemeint sind. Das ist zwar an sich per Definition schon so, aber mancheiner/innen/inniger/innes.... glaubt, sich durch gezielte Umdeutung benachteiligt fühlen zu müss*innen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Man muss durchaus nicht immer eine männliche und eine weibliche Form parallel nennen. In der Belletristik - einem Roman etwa - wirst du diese Verwendung auch nie finden, und im etablierten Journalismus nur selten. Das pärchenweise Aufführen männlicher und weiblicher Formen hat sich jedoch in den letzten Jahren im behördlichen, geschäftlichen und teils auch akademischen Schriftverkehr weitgehend druchgesetzt. Treibender Faktor ist hier die gesellschaftliche Diskussion zur Gleichberechtigung von Männern und Frauen.

Viele Leute sehen in der Verwendung der männlichen Formen (Beamter, Schüler, Lehrer, Sportler, man) eine latente Benachteiligung oder Unterdrückung von Frauen. Um dem entgegenzuwirken, fügt man im behördlichen oder auch geschäftsmäßigen Schriftverkehr in der Regel darum die weibliche Form hinzu (Beamtin, Schülerin, Sportlerin, seltener auch: frau).

Alternativ werden auch Kombinationsformen verwendet:

> Schüler/in, Angestellte/r (mit Schrägstrich)
>
> SchülerIn, ParteigenossIn (mit großem Binnen-i)

Daneben gibt es auch Bestrebungen, schriftliche Ausdrucksformen für noch weitere Geschlechteridentitäten (jenseits von nur Mann und Frau) zu finden, etwa mit einem Sternchen oder Unterstrich: Lehrer*in - was die Möglichkeit anzeigen soll, dass man sich auch anders definiert, zum Beispiel als beides, gar nichts davon oder auch als etwas Drittes.

Es gibt auch Versuche, die als Grundform historisch gebräuchliche (oder eben auch nicht mehr durchgängig gebräuchliche) männliche Form ganz durch die weibliche zu ersetzen. Bekannt wurde die Universität Leipzig, die in der Neufassung ihrer Statuten ("Grundordnung") ausschließlich die weibliche Form verwendet (Professorin), wobei damit aber wiederum stets auch Professoren (männlicher Art) mitgemeint sein sollen ("generisches Femininum").

Für deinen eigenen Gebrauch musst du selber entscheiden, wie du schreibst. Dabei wird der Kontext deines Schreibens den Ausschlag geben. Schreibst du einen Roman, wirst du kaum

> Lehrerinnen und Lehrer machen mit Schülerinnen und Schülern einen Ausflug

schreiben (außer es wäre ironisch) sondern kurz und simpel

> Lehrer und Schüler machen zusammen einen Ausflug,

denn im Roman kommt es dir weniger auf *political correctness* an als auf gute, saubere, umstandsfreie Sprache.

Schreibst du einen Zeitungsartikel, wirst du auf die Gender-Dopplung verzichten und nur von

> Politikern aller Parteien

sprechen, kaum je von

> Politikerinnen und Politikern aller Parteien

oder von

> Bewohnern und Bewohnerinnen dieses abgelegenen Landstrichs

schon weil du auf der Zeitungsseite nicht so viel Platz hast und den Leser (huch!) nicht nerven willst.

Veröffentlichst du eine Stellenanzeige, wirst du aber in der Regel einen Platz für

> eine/n Mechatroniker/in

oder

> eine Reinigungsfachkraft (m/w)

anbieten, denn du möchtest der Welt signalisieren, dass Frauen in deiner Firma nicht benachteiligt werden (auch wenn das vielleicht nur schöne Worte sind).

Eine spaßige Beobachtung am Rande: Im Eifer des Gefechts für Gender-Gleichberechtigung versteigen sich Laienschreiber/Laienschreiberinnen manchmal auch ins Absurde. Bekannt wurden Texte aus dem Vereinsumfeld, in denen

> Unsere Mitglieder und Mitgliederinnen

zur Jahreshauptversammlung und

> Liebe Kinder und Kinderinnen

zur Faschingsfeier eingeladen wurden. Das mag aus übergroßer Furcht geschehen, bei nachlässiger Gender-Dopplung von Eiferern und/oder Eiferinnen eins auf die Mütze zu bekommen. Vielleicht kann man es als Zeichen sehen für die versteckte Vehemenz der zugrundeliegenden Diskussion.

Answer (score 2):

Versuch einer knappen Erklärung, was hier die Intention einer [geschlechtergerechten Sprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geschlechtergerechte_Sprache) ist.

In meinem Kopf enstehen nämlich beim Lesen geschlechterspezifische Bilder.

## Schüler

> [image]

## Schülerin

> [image]

Ähnliche Bilder kommen auch bei Arzt und Ärztin oder bei Bauer und Bäurin.

Mit einer geschlechtergerechten Sprache soll erreicht werden, dass nicht mehr nur ein Geschlecht automatisch im Kopf erscheint, sondern keines oder beide.

Wer Schüler/in (oder irgendeine andere gängige Variante) schreibt, möchte also zeigen, dass das biologische Geschlecht hier keine Rolle spielt. Nicht mehr, aber auch nicht weniger. Nicht nur staatliche Einrichtungen, sondern auch Privatunternehmen (inklusive StackExchange) bringen dies heute mit Umsetzen einer geschlechtergerechten Sprache zum Ausdruck.

Comment: Bin überrascht, welche Bilder in Deinem Kopf entstehen ;-)

Comment: Das generische Maskulinum hat stets per Definition beide Geschlechter gemeint, bis ein paar übereifrige Menschen das Gefühl hatten, das sei nicht so. Gleichberechtigung ist in meinen Augen extrem wichtig. Die wird aber nicht über eine Leugnung von etablierten Wortbedeutungen erreicht.

Comment: Warum hast Du die Überschriften vertauscht?

Comment: @Burki, was etwas per Definition bedeutet und welche Assoziationen es hervorruft, können zwei verschiedene Dinge sein. Genau darum geht es in dieser Antwort.

Comment: @Burki darum geht es aber hier nicht (diese Diskussion stammt aus dem letzten Jahrhundert). Es geht darum, dass wir - grammatikalisches Geschlecht hin oder her - nach wie vor nicht geschlechtsneutral denken und nur deshalb bevorzugen viele (richtig gelesen, es sind eben nicht nur ein paar wenige) eine geschlechtsgerechte Sprache.

Comment: @CarstenS genau wegen der Assoziationen habe ich die Überschriften vertauscht ;)

Comment: Wie sich schnell gezeigt hat ist die Beschränkung auf binäre Geschlechterbezeichner auch nicht hilfreich. Ein Versuch, der ursprünglichen Wortbedeutung Geltung zu verschaffen (anstatt den Empört*Innen die Deutungshoheit zu überlassen) hätte wahrscheinlich sowohl der Sprache alsauch dem Anliegen der Gleichberechtigung einen wesentlich besseren Dienst erwiesen. Und in welches Jahrhundert die Diskussion gehört, zeigt wohl auch die Vielfalt der Kommentare in diesem Thread.

Comment: @Burki: ich bin mir 100% sicher, dass wir dies auch heute nicht lösen können (und vor allem nicht hier) es geht mir hier einzig um die **wertneutrale** Beobachtung warum das heute so gemacht wird.

Comment: Hier mal ein Beispiel aus einem anderen Sprachkuklturkreis: Die gut ausgebildete bulgarische Ärztin sagt von sich "Аз съм лекар" (Ich bin Arzt) und nicht etwa "Aз съм лекарка" (Ich in Ärztin), was die Sprache ihr durchaus als Möglichkeit anböte; jedoch erzeugt offenbar die grammatisch-männliche Wortform kein Bild eines männlichen Arztes, das dann ihrem Selbstbild nicht mehr entspräche, so dass sie darum die grammatisch-weibliche Wortform vorzöge.

Comment: Sehr hübsche Mouse-over-Funktion bei den Bildern. Aber wenn ich höre "Der Hof ist voller Schüler" dann sehe ich trotzdem sowohl Mädchen als auch Jungen vor mir, ziemlich genau halbe-halbe.

Comment: @Burki + Takkat: Sprache gehorcht nicht Definitionen. Sie ist nicht definiert, und dann gesprochen worden. Im besten Fall lassen sich aus dem Sprachgebrauch Definitionen ableiten. Wenn irgendwas diese These beweist, dann das Geschlecht der Wörter im Vergleich zum Geschlecht der Bezeichneten.

Comment: @Takkat: Als nicht neutral bemängle ich gleich mal, dass erstens behauptet wird, die Sprache sei nicht neutral. Dann die Unterstellung, es gäbe eine andere, eine geschlechts- oder gendergerechte Sprache, die man auswählen könnte. Diese Sprache, die Sprechbarkeit berücksichtigt, die die Offenheit des Geschlechts (Füßgängerüberweg) gewährleistet, die komplizierte Konstruktionen bewältigt, gibt es gar nicht. Zudem sind die Änderungen nicht gerecht, weil Frauen ja besonders hervorgehoben werden, Männer jedoch nicht. Deine Position ist deswegen nicht neutral.

Comment: @userunknown: es ist nicht meine Position, denn ich habe die geschlechterneutrale Sprache nicht erfunden. Du kannst gerne dagegen sein, aber diese, deine persönliche Meinung würde die gestellte Frage nach dem "Warum" nicht beantworten.

Comment: Welche Frage nach dem Warum? Ich denke die ausführliche Darstellung auf belleslettres habe ich schon verlinkt, ich will das jetzt nicht jedes Mal tun. http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/genus-gendersprech.php Kennst Du das schon? Habe ich Deine Kritik daran übersehen?

Comment: Ich übe keine Kritik an der geschlechterneutralen Sprache - wer sie benutzen möchte soll das gerne tun. Und wenn es hilft, Diskriminierung zu mininimieren, dann umso lieber. Wenn Dir das zu weit führt, dann benutz es halt nicht. Hier werden wir das jedenfalls nicht lösen können.